# Trouble writing python program?

Tags: python, function

There's a main function, inside which the entire operation is done. Inside it, there's an if statement. I want to define a function inside that `if` function only if that `if` is satisfied. The compiler should proceed to the function defined in it and 3/4 of the program depends on the operations inside the `if`. When I run the program, the statements above if only is getting executed.

eg:

```
  def manage():
         name=raw_input("Enter name")
         pass=raw_input("Enter password")
         conf=raw_input("Confirm password")
         if(pass==conf):
               print"You can proceed!!!"
               def proceed():
                       #here rate is calculated
                       print rate
   manage()#at the very end
```

the statements above the if is getting executed only.the function inside if is not getting executed.i gave the statements in the else,but its not coming. is it possible to define function inside an if? if not,is there any package we should import? or is there some other way?

Comment: you dont execute the function inside the `if` , you just defined it ! if you want that you need to call it , with `proceed()`

Comment: You *create* the function, but never *call* it. But it would be better to define it elsewhere, and *only* call it in the `if` block.

Comment: pass is a keyword, you shouldn't use that as a variable name

Comment: Well your inner function `proceed` will be created if `if(pass==conf)` comes true. But just like you called manage function the same way you need to call proceed funtion too.

Comment: Thank you all!! your answers helped me!!

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `pass` as variable name:

```
def manage():
    name=raw_input("Enter name: ")
    Pass=raw_input("Enter password: ")
    conf=raw_input("Confirm password: ")
    if(Pass==conf):
        print"You can proceed!!!"
        proceed()

def proceed():
    print rate

manage()
```

You can't use [Python Keywords](https://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/keywords.html) as variable name

Comment: This *also* never calls `proceed`.

Comment: I thought OP will get it. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

You only declare the method inside the `if`, you don't execute it. Here is what you should do:

```
def manage():
    name=raw_input("Enter name")
    passwd=raw_input("Enter password")
    conf=raw_input("Confirm password")
    if(passwd==conf):  
        print"You can proceed!!!"
        proceed()

def proceed():
    #here rate is calculated
    print rate

manage() #at the very end
```

You should:

- declare your method `proceed` outside the `manage` method
- Call the `proceed` method when you enter the `if`
- change the `pass` variable name as it is a Python keyword

And this also assumes that the variable `rate` is declared and contains something...

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to review what a function is and does.

A function is defined within a scope, and can be within another function, but that doesn't mean it has to be inside, otherwise there is no real point to a function.

So, in short, you need to define the function(s) in the body, and **call** the function of interest when needed.

Directly from your code:

```
def proceed():
         #here rate is calculated
         print rate

def manage():
         name=raw_input("Enter name")
         passwd=raw_input("Enter password")
         conf=raw_input("Confirm password")
         if(passwd==conf):
               print"You can proceed!!!"
               proceed()

manage()#at the very end
```

I would suggest you pick up a good book on Python, like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329786), and read through it.

As noted below, the `pass` variable name is a reserved keyword in Python and will break your code. Renamed here as `passwd`.

Comment: true, i missed the pass keyword that is illegal. Corrected now.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you defined the function in the if statement, but didn't call the function.
Try add proceed() after the definition.
Something like this:

```
if(pass==conf):
               print"You can proceed!!!"
               def proceed():
                       #here rate is calculated
                       print rate
               proceed()
```